# How to find the owner of a file created on another domain?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, windows-domain, domain-security

I have a file that is owned by a user on another computer not on our domain. I am fairly certain that the original computer runs Windows Vista or 7. Our computers run Windows 7.

Is there any way to identify the username of the owner of this file? The owner currently shows up as the user's SID: `S-1-5-21-1390067357-1078081533-839522115-36844`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if you have access to the computer (or domain) it was created on, otherwise you have no way to line up the SID with the user DB it comes from.

If you can get access to that, check out this other SU question: [How to know SID of Windows' user account?](https://superuser.com/questions/231908/how-to-know-sid-of-windows-user-account)